# Pop up keeps appearing in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, xbindkeys, xev

I have bound my mouse buttons to certain actions (changing music tracks) using xbindkeys. This pop up appears only when vlc is not running and I click one of the mouse buttons.
[image: Pop up]

Comment: is it possible to show xbindkeys data?

Comment: Well yes... you've told the keys to take specific different actions, and if you're not running the app that those keys are made for, activating those keys in, say, Firefox, will give you that symbol that means "you can't do that here".

Comment: If you have dual-booted ubuntu with windows ,update windows keyboard drivers .
It worked for me